# Blues scale in Ableton, anything in Logic Pro

Tags: blues, ableton-live, logic-pro

I used Ableton and I wanted to know how I can get this in logic pro. There is a midi effect in Ableton called blues scale? How can I accomplish this in Ableton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The transposer MIDI plug-in](http://www.logic-cafe.com/lc/index.php/logic-pro-x-never-hit-a-wrong-note-again-with-the-transposer-midi-plug-in) seems to be able to restrict to a blues scale.